# Html table not generating

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to take a csv file that I have (named travelq.csv), and I'm trying to auto-generate a table from the data. The h1 heading loads but the table does not. I do not know where I went wrong. Hoping one of you lovely human(?) beings can help me out

This is my index file(index.html):

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CSV File to Table</title>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Andrew Long</h1>
        <table id="data-table" border="1">
            <!-- CSV contents will be imported here -->
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my script.js file:
//script.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    fetch('/travel')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Data Received:', data);
            const table = document.getElementById('data-table');

            //Adds Headers
            const header = table.createTHead();
            const headerRow = header.insertRow(0);
            Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(key => {
                const th = document.createElement('th');
                th.innerText = key;
                headerRow.appendChild(th);
            });

            //Adds Data to Table
            data.forEach(item => {
                const row = table.insertRow(-1);
                Object.values(item).forEach(value => {
                    const cell = row.insertCell();
                    cell.innerText = value;
                });
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data: ', error));
})
```

This is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/index.html');
});

app.get('/travel', (req, res) => {
    const data = [];

    fs.createReadStream('travelq.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (row) => {
            data.push(row)
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            res.json(data);
        });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: The code seems working. Do you see any errors while running the server?

Comment: For me the table does not generate. I essentially see this:
ANDREW LONG
.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, **DOMContentLoaded** is a premature state of document loading that one can use to take performance measurements of a website as an example, but it’s of no use to your needs.

Also, you should never omit semicolons... some are critical.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

})
```

You should replace the above listener with this to ensure the document has fully and properly loaded before attempting to populate elements with fetched data...

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){

});
```

Looking further down, you make CONSTANT declarations; meaning you have no intention of modifying them, and then attempt to add rows/columns! Go figure...

```
const header = table.createTHead();
const headerRow = header.insertRow(0);
```

They should be declared as vars... all of them.

A constant should be used for data that will never change such as the days of the week or months of the year, like this:

```
const DaysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I changed the code but unfortunately the table still doesn't generate.

Comment: That’s fair enough but you’ve got to get your basics right before you move on to secondary issues.

Comment: Avoid using vars. If you don't want to make a variable constant, use let instead.